# PyMongo throwing "E11000 duplicate key error index"

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, ipython, pymongo

Duplicate documents are expected to be inserted into the mongodb collection, so an index was created with `unique=True` and `dropDups=True`.

```
db.myCollection.create_index("timestamp", unique=True, dropDups=True)
```

However if the same set of documents are inserted twice, the first insert goes fine but the second insert throws the error

```
db.myCollection.insert(json.loads(df.to_json()).values())
```

`DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: myDb.myCollection.$timestamp_1  dup key: { : 1385290560000000000 }`

I am confused as to why `dropDups=True` is not working.

Comment: Why not do bulk inserts with continueOnError set to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dropDups` only affects an existing collection by deleting duplicate documents at the [time of index creation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates). It does not however later stop the exception/error from being raised. When you try to insert the same document twice, an error will always be thrown if you use `insert`. You could consider using an `upsert` ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db.collection.save) and via `findAndModify` ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/))) which could be configured to conditionally apply the new document instead of raising an exception.

You might consider keeping a hash of timestamps locally if possible to avoid calling the database entirely (occasionally, you'd need to purge the hash table to prevent unbounded growth).

Or, don't enable the index until after you've inserted the data (if possible).

Comment: Is it possible to do a bulk `upsert`? My data is already nicely packed as a pandas dataframe converted to json format

Comment: No, it's not possible. `upsert` would change multiple documents (but not insert multiple documents).